# How to simplify a problem with two variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

I am trying to solve this problem.

Let $\Delta$ be a positive number. I would like to find the values of $x$ and $y$ such that:

$$ 
\left(1+\dfrac{x}{1+y}\right)\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{y}{1+x}\right) \geqslant \Delta,\quad (P1)
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are restricted to be non-negative numbers, i.e., $x>0$ and $y>0$.

How to express $(P1)$ in an equivalent form more simple? Like  $(P1) \iff x \geqslant \Delta' \cdot y$.

Comment: Your question has too many answers: you should tell us what you want to do with the simpler form. One option is to multiply both sides by $(1+x)(1+y)$, so $(1+x+y)^2\geq\Delta(1+x)(1+y)$.

Comment: I want to transform the problem of maximizing the function in the left-hand side of $(P1)$ to a problem of maximizing/minimizing $x$ or maximizing/minimizing $y$. I plot the function and I see that $x$ has to be greater than something and $y$ less than something or vice versa.

Comment: Let y' = y + 1 and x'= x + 1 and you get (1 + x'/y' - 1/y')(1 + y'/x' - 1/x') >= delta.  Let's assume y'<=x' then 1 + x'/y' - 1/y' > 2delta so x' - 1 >(2delta  - 1)y' so either x > (2delta - 1)(y + 1) or y > 2delta - 1)(x + 1).  Does that help.

Comment: @fleablood So $(P1)$ is equivalent to $x\geqslant(2\Delta-1)\cdot(1+y)$ or $y\geqslant(2\Delta-1)\cdot(1+x)$ ?

Comment: but $\left(1+\frac{x}{1+y}\right)\left(1+\frac{y}{1+x}\right)>1$ is hold since $x>0$,$y>0$

Comment: Not equivalent  as I only did the argument one way and *strictly* greater than (never equal) but unless I made an error (1+ x/(y+1))(1 + y/(x+1)) $\ge$ delta  $\implies$  either x > (2delta -1)(1 + y) if y $\le$ x or y > (2delta -1)(1 + x) if x $\le$ y.  But perhaps someone should check my math.